# Python : for loop for multi variables

Tags: python, numpy, loops

It seems a simple question, but I'm new to Python.

I have 10 variables (those names are from `A` to `J`), those variables are `float32 np.arrays`. I want to apply the following command :

```
variable = variable*mask[0,:,:]; variable[variable==0] = np.nan
```

On **all** variables, **just in one line** rather than writing 10 lines, taking into account keeping variables names the same.

Psuedocode exmaple

```
FOR all variables A-J
    variable = variable*mask[0,:,:]; variable[variable==0] = np.nan
ENDFOR
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this?

```py
variables = [a,b,c]

for i in range(len(variables)):
    x = variables[i]
    variables[i] = x*mask[0,:,:]; x[x==0] = np.nan
```

note: *this just updates the items in the list*

Comment: Thanks Freddy Mcloughlan for your comment, it works with me. Also, I've found that if we want to update the variable per se, we can re-export it from the list as following :

list = [*range(0, len(variables))]
a,b,c = [variables[i] for i in (list)]

Comment: Awesome, your solution is very good, I recommend posting it as an answer to this question, but not using `list` as a variable name, as `list` is a standard python class